# Applying percentage change (a time-series) to a single number to create a new time-series?

Tags: r, percentage

i'm new to R. I have a time series (YOY.relative.change) that consists of the percentage increase in carbon emissions. I would like to apply YOY.relative.change to a single starting number (X) to create a new time series. To do so I will need to multiply the product of (X * (1 + YOY.relative.change[1]) by (1 + YOY.relative.change[2]) and so on..

```
YOY.relative.change
[1] 0.000000000 0.012931034 0.012765957 0.012605042 0.012448133
[6] 0.012295082 0.012145749 0.008000000 0.007936508 0.007874016
[11] 0.007812500 0.007751938  

starting.number = 2000

expected.output
[1] 2000 2025.58 2051.5 etc.
```

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for the advice. Yes, I want to create a vector. I have a vector (X) of 12 numbers that represent the percentage increase in each year between 2004 and 2015 which were calculated from another vector using this function: pcchange = function (x,lag=1) c(diff(x, lag), rep(NA, lag)) / x. I want to apply vector X to the number 2000 to create a vector of absolute values starting at 2000. Is this clearer?

Comment: If it is only 12 numbers, why not post `YOY.relative.change`, a starting number, and expected output? Note that base R has a useful time series object which goes beyond a simple numeric vector. Evaluate `?ts` in the console to get some info.

Comment: That would have been much clearer. Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: Where did `2258` come from? That is a `12.9%` increase, but `0.0129` is `1.29%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started:

```
apply.changes <- function(seed,changes){
  n <- length(changes)
  nums <- numeric(n+1)
  nums[1] <- seed
  for(i in 1:n){
    nums[i+1] <- (1+changes[i])*nums[i]
  }
  nums
}

YOY.relative.change <- c(0.000000000, 0.012931034, 0.012765957, 0.012605042, 0.012448133, 0.012295082, 0.012145749, 0.008000000, 0.007936508, 0.007874016, 0.007812500, 0.007751938)
v <- apply.changes(2000,YOY.relative.change)
```

Then `v` is:

```
[1] 2000.000 2000.000 2025.862 2051.724 2077.586 2103.448 2129.310 2155.172
[9] 2172.414 2189.655 2206.897 2224.138 2241.379
```

My code includes the original seed value, though it seems that you might not want that. In that case `v[-1]` evaluates to a vector of the same length as `YOY.relative.changes`.

Comment: Thankyou, John. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: or maybe `2000 * cumprod(1+YOY.relative.change)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck That would be better.